get the file address using / instead of \
I encountered the following problem: I need to pass a link to the file in the backgroun-image. Данный файл лежит в папке storage/test/... The address for it is stored in the database in the form of \May2024\f4sOIqLjhYnhVNdNtxwM.png
Using the command below I don't get what I need.
<div style="background-image: url({{url("$tt->image")}});

I get the following: url(http://laravel.l/test\May2024\f4sOIqLjhYnhVNdNtxwM.png)
And this is not what is needed. But if you replace \ with / then everything works as it should. Please help.

There should be cleaner way of replacing those characters right in template, bud generally speaking in PHP, you can use str_replace.
str_replace('\', '/', 'your\string');


That's what I think. After all, using this method <img src="storage/{{$tt->image}}"> everything works as it should.
